# Large data set exceeding maximum execution time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is loading the contents of a spreadsheet into scriptDB but the spreadsheet has around 15,000 rows, 9 columns and keeps giving me an "exceeded maximum execution time" error.

I'm using the function given in Google's documentation to load the data:

```
function loadDatabaseFromSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_KEY);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var columns = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var keys = data[0];
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var rowData = data[row];
    var item = {};
    for (var column = 0; column < keys.length; column++) {
      item[keys[column]] = rowData[column];
    }
    db.save(item);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to speed things up or am I just going to have to break it up into chunks of a few thousand?

Comment: ScriptDB is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `db.save(item)` 15000 times is what is causing the slowness. Instead, use [bulk operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#bulk_operations) if you're going to be saving that much data.

```
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var items = [];
  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var rowData = data[row];
    var item = {};
    for (var column = 0; column < keys.length; column++) {
      item[keys[column]] = rowData[column];
    }
    items.push(item);
  }
  db.saveBatch(items,false);
```

Calling the save operation once at the end saves you all of the round-trip times, so this should speed up your code a lot and finish before it exceeds the maximum execution time.

Comment: worked great, thanks Phil. I feel kinda embarrassed I didn't see that myself.

Comment: This definitely solved my issue!!! But had one more question here. Do we have similar thing to delete the data from DB? Current I am using this [code] (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#deleting_all_items_from_the_database) to delete the contents. But this is also timing out and i need to run this code atleast twice or thrice to cleanup the up. Any work around?

Comment: Did you take a look at [the removeBatch method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/script-db-instance#removeBatch(ScriptDbMap,Boolean))?